# How do i pass a subclass by non-constant reference

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, subclassing

I am writing a unit test for `A::some_method()` which accepts class `B` as follows:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    some_method(B (&obj)[a_big_number]);
}
```

Class `B` (Bad Class) has an ugly interface:

```cpp
class B {
public: 
    get_value(int index);
    set_value(int index, value);
}
```

The reason I don't like this interface is that `get_value(i)` does not map to the same element as `set_value(i)`.  Someone thought it was a good idea to have a complicated mapping to the underlying array when getting the value.  This mapping is created and developed by some third class `C`, which is not relevant here.

This means I either need to reverse engineer this unrelated mapping in order enter test data into class `B`, or somehow bypass it.

To bypass the complicated mapping, I want to create a subclass called `B_Mock`, as follows:

```cpp
class B_Mock: public B {
public:
    get_value(int index) {/*code that just returns the index referenced by set_value(index)*/}
}
```

And then instantiate it in my unit test as:

```cpp
A a;
B_Mock inputs_outputs[1000];
/* code that repeatedly calls set_value() for each element of inputs_outputs with an initial value. */
```

Once `inputs_outputs` is set up, I want to call `a.some_method(inputs_outputs)` to verify that that `some_method()` works correctly.

Here are my issues:

- If I simply call `a.some_method(inputs_outputs)`, I get the following compiler error:

  > a reference of type "A (&)[1000]" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "B_Mock [1000]"'
- I cannot change the interface of `A::some_method()` to `A::some_method(const B (&obj)[a_big_number])`, because `some_method()` calls `obj[index].set_value()`.
- It does compile successfully if I change the interface of `A::some_method()` to `A::some_method(const B obj[a_big_number])` and pass by value.  I do not want to do this, since (1) `obj` is a rather large array of large objects, and (2) I need to access the modified data in `inputs_outputs` after `a.some_method()` operates on it, to verify that updates were made correctly.  Passing by value will not return the modified objects.

How do I pass in my subclassed `B_Mock` to `A.some_method()` in a way that allows me to see the modified objects via the `inputs_outputs` parameter?

Comment: I strongly recommend not using fantasy code in your examples. Use real examples, and in the cases where you really don't know what something should look like in C++ be brutally obvious about it and try your best.

Comment: What you are attempting to do will not work. `A::some_method()` takes a a reference to a `B[]` array of objects. You can't give it any `B_Mock` objects, as they will get [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) when put into a `B[]` array. Besides, `B_Mock` won't work anyway unless `B::get_value()` is `virtual`. What you would have to do instead is dynamically patch `B` at runtime to point `B::get_value()` at another implementation, such as with a detour.

Comment: Arrays are not polymorphic. Your third example compiles because you’re passing a pointer instead of an array, but it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: The error message about initializing `A (&)[1000]` does not match the code show.  Are you sure the message does not say `B (&)[1000]` instead?